# Which one of Aristotle's four causes is this?

Tags: aristotle, causation, cause-and-effect

Consider this exchange spoken in a hypothetical dialogue about man choosing his own personality:

> Every phlegmatic man is made when he realizes that his original fiery disposition will become his own undoing. The fiery disposition is the cause and the phlegmatic temperament is the effect.

What type of cause is "fiery disposition" to "phlegmatic temperament"? It cannot be an efficient cause, because a fiery disposition is sufficient for a choleric temperament. But in this case, the fiery disposition is causing a choleric temperament.

Comment: Efficient causes rarely act "by their own power" alone (i.e. they are rarely [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Necessary_and_sufficient_causes) for the effect), said power is typically combined with other efficient causes and circumstances. The claim made in this passage is that the "fiery disposition" can combine with  circumstances to ultimately effect,  through "realization", phlegmatic temperament instead of choleric one.

Comment: @Conifold Yes. That is correct. And how would scholars of Aristotle classify that type of cause? Your wonderful explanation also caused the original post to get updated.

Comment: Aristotle classifies causes by the nature of causing, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-causality/#FourCaus). This cause is efficient because it effects the outcome rather than serves as its form, material or goal. Whether the cause is sufficient only matters for determining whether the given explanation is complete. In Aristotle's examples, listed causes are typically sufficient under normal circumstances, he tries to be comprehensive. But they need not be for classification purposes, parts of efficient causes are themselves efficient, of formal causes are formal, etc.

Comment: @Conifold What an amazing explanation! *S'il vous plaît*, write it as a complete answer so I can upvote it and award you the green check mark.